# IBM Iseries security questions

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I am new to Iseries, my manager is off today. Someone asked me for a list of users that have access to certain programs.

I google and I am not even sure what to ask for in my search. Is there a command I can use that if I specify the module/program name it will return list of users who have access? and also a list of which access templates include these programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Display Object Authority](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzarl/rzarlauthaud.htm) command, `DSPOBJAUT`

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to mark this as the answer. Thank you!